# Keras Model Performance decreased after change from Batch to Single Image Load

Tags: python, validation, keras

I have built a model in Keras, normally I trained, validated it by using `ImageDataGenerator`, the performance of the network is quite good. However, when I tried to load the same image into the model by this manner:

```
img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
img_orig = image.img_to_array(img)
preds = model.predict(preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(img_orig.copy(), axis=0)))
```

the prediction is very poor. I tried this on all sets(train, test, validation), they all resulted in poor prediction.

I think the difference come from the fact that in ImageDataGenerator, I use `rescale=1./255`, but I don't have that in the single image load, but I don't know how to apply rescale to this.

Is my idea correct about this issue? And how can I fix it?

Comment: On how many images did you test this way? if it's very few, maybe those were edge cases. Why don't you rescale and try with single image loads?

Comment: I tried a lot of images, also in different classes. I tried to apply img_orig = img_orig*1./255 but the array result is still the same. I’m not quite sure that my syntax is correct, of course.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen What is the `preprocess_input`? Could you post its code? Did you use it on the images during training as well? For rescaling you just need to use: `img_orig /= 255.`.

Comment: the `preprocess_input` is from keras image_utils, I checked it code and it already included the rescale part. In the training, I used rescale = 1./255 in `ImageDataGenerator`.

I have used `img_orig /= 255. `, and the network works normally. I'm quite confuse about why `preprocess_input` didn't work as intended